# Is there a way to remove specific combinations of punctuation in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been iterating over soup that I have scraped, and part of the data I need is so close to being right, but I just cant get the last part clean. Is there a simple way for the following.

I've tried to use re and join, but neither work, due to the fact that the way the punctuation shows up is varied.

```
I want to turn this:
"['Coming To ', America]", "['Captain ', America, ': The Winter...']", 
"[America, 'n Pie']", "[America, 'n Made']"

Into this:
'Coming To America', 'Captain America: The Winter...', 'American Pie', 
'American Made'
```

Comment: To match the characters you want to remove, the regex would be: (["\[}+)(["\]]+).  The format of your input matters though, is it an array?

Comment: Its a list, which I am looping over to build a list of tuples. I am iterating over the list as I build the list of tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are probably reading python code from a file, you should use eval as this is the most generic method to compute what you want.

This avoids adding a new line of replace each time a new character appears (such as tabs or parenthesis), but this also leads to security breaches if you are not careful with what you are doing

The `eval` function lets a Python program run Python code within itself.

You need to define the variable `America` to make it a valid python statement, then you can `eval` this to a list and then join each part

```
s = ["['Coming To ', America]", "['Captain ', America, ': The Winter...']", "[America, 'n Pie']", "[America, 'n Made']"]
America = 'America'
for x in s:
    print(''.join(eval(x)))
```

Output :

```
Coming To America
Captain America: The Winter...
American Pie
American Made
```

Comment: That eval function seems very handy! Thanks mate.

Comment: The eval function is dangerous, i think it's better to use other parsing function like ``json.loads`` or ``ast``

Answer (score 1):

use `map()` on the list and `filter()` on each string in the list:

```
lst = ["['Coming To ', America]", "['Captain ', America, ': The Winter...']", 
    "[America, 'n Pie']", "[America, 'n Made']"]
punct = set(list("[],'\n"))
print(list(
    map(lambda s: ''.join(filter(lambda c: c not in punct, s)), lst)
))
```

Outputs:

```
['Coming To  America', 'Captain  America : The Winter...', 'America n Pie', 'America n Made']
```

if you want to remove other characters just add them to `punct`

Comment: The problem with that is I am left with a number of unwanted spaces. Thanks for the input though

Comment: well then you're problem isn't just getting rid of punctuation, it's a lot harder than that, for example take `America n Pie` how is the program supposed to know you mean `american pie`, what if it's really meant to be `America n Pie`?

Comment: Exactly, I've already iterated it down to this from a more complex structure. But, it may be that I have made a mistake earlier on and now I cant get exactly what I want.

Comment: what you want is more of an NLP problem

Comment: Turns out I was using .content instead of .text from BeautfulSoup. Thanks for the help none the less!

Answer (score 1):

Using [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) for this might be overdoing it, but anyway here is a way:

```
import ast

# AST visitor that transforms names into strings
class NamesAsStrings(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Name(self, node):
        return ast.copy_location(ast.Str(
            s=node.id,
            ctx=node.ctx
        ), node)

ss = ("['Coming To ', America]",
      "['Captain ', America, ': The Winter...']",
      "[America, 'n Pie']",
      "[America, 'n Made']")
visitor = NamesAsStrings()
strs = [''.join(ast.literal_eval(visitor.visit(ast.parse(s)).body[0].value)) for s in ss]
print(*strs, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
Coming To America
Captain America: The Winter...
American Pie
American Made
```

This works only if non-string elements (here `America`) are valid Python names. However, it has the advantage that it will deal correctly with escaped characters in the strings.

Comment: ast looks like a handy function. Always good to see different ways to solve a problem. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

The function that you want is the `replace` method of the strings.

It's syntax is like this :

```
newString = oldString.replace("oldSubstring", "newSubstring")
```

So, using it to resolve your problem would look like this:

```
a = ["['Coming To ', America]", "['Captain ', America, ': The Winter...']",  "[America, 'n Pie']", "[America, 'n Made']"]

result = []
toRemove = ["', ", ", '", "'", "[", "]"]
for element in a:
  b = element
  for punct in toRemove:
    b = b.replace(punct, "")
  result.append(b)
print("\n".join(result))
```

Comment: Be careful this is not giving the right output, you still have square brackets